# Slugfield not working if field name is different from slug

Tags: django, url, slug

Good evening, Django is completely new for me and it's my first question here.
I'm trying to create a Webapp. I'm using Django, Python and MariaDB.
I created a project with two apps and I have a model for each app. In the fist one I used "slug" as field name and everything is working fine. In the second one I wanted to differentiate that field giving a different name (bk_slug) defined as SlugField. I tried to use the same kind of instructions lines and modifying them for the field name it seems not working. I cannot have the right URL (Class based ListView) and cannot access to the Class based DetailView....
Thanks in advance  for your support.

models.py

````py
    from django.db import models
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.urls import reverse
    
    # book masterdata
    
    
    class Book(models.Model):
        bk_title = models.CharField("Book Title", max_length=100, 
            primary_key=True)
        bk_originaltitle = models.CharField("Book original Title", 
            max_length=100, blank=True)
        bk_author = models.CharField("Author", max_length=50)
        bk_editor = models.CharField("Editor", max_length=50)
        bk_editiondate = models.CharField("Book Edition date", 
            max_length=30)
        bk_recblocked = models.BooleanField("Book record blocked")
        bk_creator = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
            related_name='+', verbose_name="Created by")
        bk_creationdate = models.DateTimeField("Creation date", 
            auto_now=True)
        bk_modifier = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
            on_delete=models.PROTECT,                                    
            related_name='+', verbose_name="Last modification by")
        bk_modified = models.DateTimeField("Last modification date", 
            auto_now=True)
        bk_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, allow_unicode=True, 
            blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.bk_title
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('book_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.bk_slug})

urls.py

    from django.urls import path
    
    from dimlibrary.views import BookListView
    from dimlibrary.views import BookDetailView
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', BookListView.as_view(), name='book_list'),
        path('<slug:bk_slug>/', BookDetailView.as_view(), 
            name='book_detail'),
    ]

views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render
    
    # Create your views here.
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.views.generic.list import ListView
    from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
    
    from dimlibrary.models import Book
    
    # book views :
    # List view
    class BookListView(ListView):
    
        model = Book
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return context 
            
    
    # Details View
    class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    
        model = Book
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return context

```html

    {% extends 'base/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
    
    <h1>Books List</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for book in object_list %}
            <li><a href="{{ dimlibrary.book.get_absolute_url }}">{{ 
                          book.bk_title }}</a> - {{ book.bk_author }} - 
                  {{ book.bk_editor }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No book registred yet.</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    
    
    {% endblock content %}
````

Comment: Can you share the model, view, urls, etc. for your second app?

Comment: Hi Willem, I inserted my code as requested, thanks in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DetailView`, you need to specify the [**`slug_field`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) as `'bk_slug'`:

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    slug_field = 'bk_slug'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

In the model, you will need to [**`slugify(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) the name, so:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Book(models.Model):
    # …

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.bk_slug:
            self.bk_slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```