# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'view_director' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['crew/view_director/(?P<dslug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']

Tags: django

i made two apps called **crew** which contains the table **Director** and **movie** which contains the table **Movie**
when i try to click this link, it shows the error given above.

`<a href="{% url 'crew:view_director' director.slug %}"> <img src="{{mov.director.photo.url}}" class="card-img-top rounded-0" alt="..."> </a>`

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from crew import views
app_name='crew'
urlpatterns = [
    # function based path
    path('view_director/<slug:dslug>',views.view_director,name='view_director'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from crew.models import *

# Create your views here.
def view_director(request,dslug):
    director=Director.objects.get(slug=dslug)
    return render(request,'director_detail.html',{'director':director})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# from movie.models import Movie

# Create your models here.

class Director(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='crew/director')
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,blank=True)
    # movies=models.ForeignKey(movie.Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

also iam not getting the directors name and image from this code on the movie detail page

```
<div class="card rounded-0" style="width: 14rem;">
  <a href="">
   <img src="{{mov.director.photo.url}}" class="card-img-top rounded-0" alt="...">
  </a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{mov.director.name}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Director</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i get the director detail page and display those details on the movie detail page, what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: The director slug is empty

Comment: How can i fix it?...

Comment: How to fill slug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512060/slugfield-not-working-if-field-name-is-different-from-slug